# how to load file from google cloud to job

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, pyspark, pickle

i stored file on drive "/content/drive/My Drive/BD-CW2" filename
   pickleRdd same as job read_rdd.py

but when i run job on cluster im getting

Traceback (most recent call last):   File
   "/tmp/18dcd2bf5c104f01b6d25ea6919b7cfc/read_rdd.py", line 55, in
   
       read_RDD(sys.argv[1:])     File "/tmp/18dcd2bf5c104f01b6d25ea6919b7cfc/read_rdd.py", line 32, in
   read_RDD

code to read file inside job

```
RDDFromPickle  = open('pickleRdd', 'rb')

RDDFromPickle = pickle.load(RDDFromPickle)
```

how I can redirect above code it to read
   from drive(/content/drive/My Drive/BD-CW2) ?
or move file from drive to cluster so job can access it ?
all work fine when i run on colab only cannot access when i run on cluster

easiet way seems be to adjust

```
 RDDFromPickle  = open('/content/drive/My Drive/BD-CW2/pickleRdd', 'rb')
```

but how i can pass google drive location ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using Google Cloud Platform, I guess you are deploying your pyspark file to Cloud Dataproc. If so, I suggest to upload your file to a buket in Google Cloud Storage and read from there this file using the code as follows (guess it's a CSV file):

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession \
   .builder \
   .appName('dataproc-python-demo') \
   .getOrCreate()

df = spark.read.format("csv").option("header", 
     "false").load("gs://<bucket>/file.csv")

count_value = df.rdd.map(lambda line: (line._c0, line._c1)).count()

print(count_value)
```

In the code above it created a Dataframe and I turned it into RDD type to format the values, but you can also use the Dataframe type to do it.

Note that _c0 and _c1 is the default name of the columns it gets when the CSV files have no header. Once you got a similar code like this, you can submit it to your dataproc cluster this way:

```
gcloud dataproc jobs submit pyspark --cluser <cluster_name> --region 
<region, example us-central1> gs://<bucket>/yourpyfile.py
```

In order to submit a new job in Dataproc you can refer to this link [1].

[1] https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/guides/submit-job#submitting_a_job

Comment: thanks for detailed explanation im using actually picke file but after you gave all details i can manage all easily

Answer (score 0):

Use module **os** with **abspath** as follows:

```
import os.path
RDDFromPickle = open(os.path.abspath('/content/drive/My Drive/BD-CW2/pickleRdd', 'rb'))
RDDFromPickle = pickle.load(RDDFromPickle)
```

Comment: Hi It will not work   im still getting   File "/tmp/8dcaa3f4bf634ef4912f6f4b25e155cf/read_rdd.py", line 60, in <module>
    read_RDD(sys.argv[1:])  
  File "/tmp/8dcaa3f4bf634ef4912f6f4b25e155cf/read_rdd.py", line 37, in read_RDD
    RDDFromPickle = open(os.path.abspath('/content/drive/My Drive/BD-CW2/pickleRdd'), 'rb')
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/content/drive/My Drive/BD-CW2/pickleRdd'

Comment: Please write the full code block you're using for this task. It's important to get the complete information for accurate debugging.

Comment: %%writefile read_cloud.py 
    import pickle
    import os.path
    RDDFromPickle = open(os.path.abspath('/content/drive/My Drive/BD- 
    CW2/pickleRdd'), 'rb')
    #RDDFromPickle = open(RDDFromPickle, 'rb')
    RDDFromPickle = pickle.load(RDDFromPickle)

Comment: and to run job !gcloud dataproc jobs submit pyspark --cluster $CLUSTER --region $REGION \
    ./read_cloud.py \    apologises for formatting

Comment: Firstly, please put your codes between a pair of ``` to correctly format your questions/comments. Your OP was well formatted, but your comments aren't helping to figure out the issue.
Secondly, what are the contents of pickleRdd? It looks like it has some call to read_rdd.py, which isn't able to get your path correctly.

Comment: `%%writefile read_cloud.py import pickle import os.path RDDFromPickle = open(os.path.abspath('/content/drive/My Drive/BD- CW2/pickleRdd'), 'rb')  RDDFromPickle = pickle.load(RDDFromPickle) `                                                      and jobcode                                                                                                         
 `!gcloud dataproc jobs submit pyspark --cluster $CLUSTER --region $REGION \ ./read_cloud.py \ `   file is pickled RDD [link to file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1-2NG8Tq8AdSyL5RqX_SH56OWRb8gdwfH) thanks for help !